# calculate transform attribute of a g element inside an svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

am using d3.layout.cloud.js from [here](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html), to create a cloud, i've edited the svg with and height, but i don't understant how to calculate the translate params `.attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")` for this function

```
    function draw(words) {
        d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(230, 200)")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            })
            .style("fill", function() {
                return getRundomColor();
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.text;
            });
    }
```

the width of svg element is `848` and the height is `400`.

my question is how can i calculate the transform attr for the `g` element?

Comment: You translate by half the width and half the height so the new element is centred.